# Safe to use WMI to remotely recycle IIS app pools on production servers?

Tags: iis, wmi

What are the downsides to enabling & using WMI to remotely manage IIS?
I plan to have a specific user account (non-admin) with only Execute Methods, Enable Account, and Remote Enable WMI permissions on the root\MicrosoftIISv2 namespace.  It will be used primarily to recycle various app pools, no changing any settings.

Are there any other security or performance concerns I need to be aware of with this solution?  Accessing WMI can only be done over our VPN, and only either Admins or this heavily restricted account have access to WMI.  Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks